# SSIS data conversion casting a NULL instead of throwing an error

Tags: ssis

I am trying to use the Data Conversion component to convert a string to and int. I am anticipating some bad data (for example 101A, instead of 101) and set up a destination for error causing rows. In testing, the column with bad data was cast as NULL, instead of throwing an error.

Is there a means to have the data conversion throw an error if it can't convert to an int? Or should I used a Script Component and roll my transformation?

Thanks

UPDATE: Looks like the column is NULL before getting to the Data Conversion. I am using an Excel Data source and the bad data is null form that point.

My original goal remains in that I want the bad data directed to a file recording the error rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not handle this in a conditional split before attempting to convert? Check to see if its numeric or not and only put through the values that can be converted into the Data Conversion. Someone wrote a very good article on how to do this [here](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/dustinryan/ssis/915/check-isnumeric-with-derived-column-transform-in-ssis-package).

Comment: Good call. I'll go in that direction.